# Rooting HTC Gratia

Tags: rooting

I've been trying to root my HTC Gratia for weeks, with no success. I found no specific tutorial, so I used those for HTC Aria, which should be basically the same phone. Can anyone give me specific information that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly have you tried so far and what happened?

In any case, unrevoked should work to get you root.  There's a step-by-step [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=788737) on XDA.

Comment: I have tried unrevoked, revolutionary and a tutorial for the cyanogenmod ROM. None of them worked.

Comment: @Varaix : Is your device S-on or s-off?  Bootloader unlocked?

Comment: How can I find out?

Comment: shut off the device, then hold down the "volume down" button while pressing power.  You should get a white screen with a skateboarding android at the bottom.  The 2nd line will say something like "VIVO PVT SHIP S-OFF RL" (That's the line from my s-off Incredible S) if you're s-off or will mention "unlocked" (usually in the pink bit at the top) in some manner if the bootloader is unlocked.

Comment: It says "LIBERTY PVT SHIP S-ON". aLSO, hboot VERSION IS 1.00.0000

Comment: @variax: That explains matters.  Basically any attempt to root is going to fail without an unlocked bootloader or s-off.  You've got two options.  1. use the offical HTC bootloader unlock at htcdev.com.  I believe selecting the Aria should work for your device, but I'm not certain.  This will get you an unlocked bootloader suitable for obtaining root and flashing custom ROMs, but leaves carrier locks and the radio firmware lock in place.  more in next comment

Comment: @Variax  Option 2 is to get a full s-off by upgrading the hboot and using revolutionary (instructions [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1133446), though you will use the new revolutionary rather than alpharevX).  The s flag is basically the master switch for HTC devices and getting s-off will also remove any carrier lock (Allowing you to use your phone with any carrier) and allow you to flash the radio firmware.

Comment: This didn't work either. Apparently there's an issue with the NAND flash memory preventing it from getting S-OFF

Comment: Which option did you use?  The bootloader unlock or the s-off?